# Does the Lindeberg condition hold for this random variable as $n\to\infty$?

Tags: probability-theory

> Suppose we have a sequence of independent random variables $\xi_n$,
>   with $P(\xi_n = 1) = P(\xi_n = -1) = \frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$, 
>   and $P(\xi_n = \sqrt{n}) = P(\xi_n = -\sqrt{n}) = \frac{1}{2n^2}$. 
>   Show that the Central Limit Theorem holds for $\xi_1+\xi_2+\ldots+\xi_n$.

First, it is clear that $E(\xi_i) = 0$, and so $Var(\xi_i) = 1-\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n}$. Now if we set $s_n^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n Var(\xi_i)$, it is then clear that $s_n^2$ grows like $n$. In particular, $s_n$ grows like $\sqrt{n}$. On the other hand, note that $|\xi_i|$ is at most $\sqrt{n}$.

Now in order to apply the [Lindeberg's condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindeberg's_condition), we want to show that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{s_n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n E(\xi_i^2 \cdot \chi_{\{|\xi|\geq \epsilon s_n\}}) \to 0$$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

**Here is where I got stuck:** let us compute $E(\xi_i^2 \cdot \chi_{\{|\xi|\geq \epsilon s_n\}})$ for sufficiently large $n$. Now we can note that for sufficiently large $n$, the set $\left\{\frac{|\xi_k|}{s_n} \geq \epsilon\right\}$ is at most some $\delta$ distance away from $1$, for $0<\delta<<\sqrt{n}$. Hence, $E(\xi_i^2 \cdot \chi_{\{|\xi|\geq \epsilon s_n\}})$ is at most $(1 - \frac{1}{n^2})$, and since $s_n^2$ grows like $n$, we do not necessarily have that $\frac{1}{s_n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n E(\xi_i^2 \cdot \chi_{\{|\xi|\geq \epsilon s_n\}})$ converges to zero.

(1) Is it possible to salvage the above attempt? If not, when does the Lindberg condition fail to hold, but a sequence still has a Central Limit Theorem-behavior?

(2) If the above cannot be salvaged, how else can one show this result?

Comment: You write $$Var(\xi_i) = 1-\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n}$$ Perhaps you mean $$Var(\xi_i) = 1-\frac{1}{i^2}+\frac{1}{i}$$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $n$ large enough so that $n > \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$. This implies that the $k$-th term in the sum is basically $\approx \frac{1}{k}$. So the whole series is bounfed above by $\approx \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} \approx \log n$ by the asymptotics of the harmonic series. Therefore, the series dies as $n \rightarrow \infty$ after dividing by $s_n^2 \approx n$.

Comment: Excellent! So all I needed to do is look away from the $\xi_k = \pm 1$.